# French accents not showing correctly in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, texmaker, accents, french

I am writing in French and there are many accents. I can see them in the whole document except in the table of contents.

When I compile and preview my document in Texmaker, I can see the french accent in the table of contents:

[image]

But when I check the actual pdf that is produced with Adobe Acrobat Reader or Preview/Aperçu (Mac OS X 10.6.8 default pdf viewer), the accents are replaced by special characters as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

This is a part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
```

The TOC file entries look like:

```
\select@language {french}
\contentsline {section}{Introduction}{1}{section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Contexte actuel}{2}{section.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Contexte socio-\'economique}{2}{subsection.1.1}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably you have to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34608/13670

Comment: If I use just utf8 I  have to type all accents like `\'{e}` and I have to write around 20 pages like that. There are too many accents to type. Besides, I get this error `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�de not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: How does one of the entries look in the. toc-file?

Comment: Are your source tex files properly saved in the utf8 format?

Comment: I had started it in LyX a longtime ago and then after getting a new drive in my machine, and reinstalling my OS, I switched from LyX to Texmaker and when I open my file it tells me that the encoding cannot be properly read and I have to choose one in a long list from ISO .... to UTF... I tried to create a document from scratch in TexMaker and copy paste everything but I get error and I cannot compile it.

Comment: maybe it's a font embedding problem. You could try `\usepackage{lmodern}` like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464140/embedding-fonts-in-pdf-from-latex-source-with-pdflatex

Comment: Yes that works. But I have to write in Time News Roman 12pt well they said or an equivalent font... but school can be annoying about that.

Comment: Then I think you should have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex to know how to embed the fonts You use in the pdf.

Comment: Well I found the problem I was using `\usepackage{mathpmx}` with `\usepackage{amsfont}` just by deleting the second one it would fix the accent problem and keep the font as "Times News Roman"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the package `usepackage{amsfont}`. I didn't notice that I was using two fonts packages at the same time.

Comment: this is indeed peculiar.  `amsfonts` is loaded automatically by `amssymb`, and you have also specified that, but haven't said that you removed it.  so you are still loading `amsfonts` (check your log).  thus it appears that `amsfonts` may actually be compatible with `mathptmx`, just not when loaded twice.  if you can confirm this, i will put it on the ams list of things to be looked into.

Comment: I am using 
`\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}` and it works now but before that I had one extra `amsfonts`

Answer (score 1):

Try loading:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

If this doesn't work, then please try:

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
```

Comment: I fixed it with the font package but I cannot choose the comment as the answer.

Comment: Well, you could wait a couple of days and post the answer yourself, or if you want I can edit mine to include yours

Comment: I posted my answer. lol