# Change with Adobe Pro a PDF document generated with LaTeX

Tags: fonts, errors, embedding, adobe

I have produced a PDF with LaTeX and now need to change something within Adobe Pro (being able to do so is a requirement by an editor). If I open the document within Adobe Pro and want to change some text I get the error message (I have it translated from german):

> For the whole or for a part of the selection is no system font available

I guess this is because the font LaTeX is using (CM) is not installed on the system. Is that correct? Can I somehow get around this (would installing the font help - didn't try because of lack of administrator rights)?

Comment: I think you'll have to embed the font. Perhaps this thread helps? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex

Comment: Tried it, didn't work...

Comment: Being more specific: pdftexDownloadBase14 is true and the ghostscript thingy isn't working either...

Comment: Please add some details and a small example. Which version of Adobe Pro? Which way did you produce the PDF (e.g. texlive 2013, pdflatex or xelatex), maybe \listfiles could be helpfull.

Comment: Normally pdflatex embeds only a subset of the fonts it uses. I guess for it to work you'd need to embed the whole thing (but I'm not sure that would work either). Two options: (1) Install the fonts in the system (can you install them for your user account? That should work.) (2) Use a different font in your document (which is already available on your system). It is a bizarre requirement. If it is that the editor needs to be able to change it, you have no choice but to go with (2) and stick to some common font you are sure the editor has.