# texmaker bullet in .eps figure equation shows infinity symbol

Tags: floats, symbols, texmaker

I am using Texmaker on windows 7 and I'm trying to include a .eps figure which has bullet symbol in it, and for some reason, Texmaker shows an infinity sign instead. I've checked my .eps file, and it shows the correct symbol, and I've also checked the .pdf file that texmaker makes, and it also has the correct symbol.

I have no idea how to diagnose this problem and I appreciate any and all help, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *Texmaker shows an infinity sign*. TeXmaker is just and editor. Are you running `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: The resulting pdf shows an infinity sign. I am running pdflatex.

Comment: Are you using `mathptmx` for your document?

Comment: You cannot include EPS figures when running PDFLaTeX. Convert the EPS to PDF first and then try again.

Comment: Actually, it's just the viewer, the pdf is fine, hmm. I tried using mathptmx, and I'm still getting the infinity sign

Comment: @Charlie The hint was because it can happen that using the same font confuses the viewer. But you should be clearer about how you include the EPS: are you doing `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: Ahh, I'm using quickbuild, which right now is doing: pdflatex + Biblatex + pdflatex (x2) + view pdf.

Comment: it's possible that the font you need is not embedded in the .eps file and the local font (with the same name) has something else at the specified location.  this question discusses the problem, but may not have a solution for you: [How to embed fonts at compile time with pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10391/579)

Comment: Has this been resolved? If not, please add an example code that reproduces the problem (you will need to make the offending`eps` file available for download from somewhere and add a link here).

Answer (score 1):

EPS was designed to import postscript code, which did not include fonts. The necessary fonts had to either be installed on the output device or downloaded with the job. PDF was created to allow pages to stand alone, including embedding fonts. So, when using EPS in publishing, standard practice was to convert any type to outlines when saving (say from Illustrator) to ensure fidelity in the final output. With PDF, you could choose to save the type without having to convert it to outlines by embedding the font. It was a great step forward.

So, as barbara beeton said, the likely culprit is that your EPS is using a typeface which is being substituted in the output process by another one with a different glyph in the bullet slot. You have two solutions. If you created the EPS, then convert the type to outlines/paths before saving, or save as PDF with embedded fonts. If you don't have the original source, try converting to PDF, but it may not work as expected if you don't have the appropriate type faces installed.