# Avoid embedding Helvetica to change to Arial

Tags: fonts

This question is essentially about the opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/39167/how-to-embed-arial-in-pdf-when-pdf-has-helvetica) combined with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex/10392#10392).

I am using Latex to create a PDF for printing, which I would ideally like to be in Arial. I've currently got it in Helvetica, but I can't persuade the `uarial` package to work. I wondered whether, given that PDF readers might replace Helvetica with Arial if the Helvetica is not embedded, this might be a work-around for getting my document into Arial.

**Does this work, and if so how is it achieved?**

I tried telling `ps2pdf` not to embed all fonts, but I seemed to end up with an alternative font embedded instead of nothing.

Comment: Instead of trying some convoluted work-around where you can't know if the pdf driver used by the printer will use it you should better get uarial working. That's not so difficult.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A lot of things become difficult when the person with the admin password to your machine doesn't believe in anything that isn't Microsoft.

Comment: You can put all files in the folder of your document. And you can load the map-file with `\pdfmapfile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wondered whether, given that PDF readers might replace Helvetica
>   with Arial if the Helvetica is not embedded, this might be a
>   work-around for getting my document into Arial.

If a font is not embedded, then the behaviour depends on the PDF viewer, user settings, OS, available fonts, and system and user font configuration.

That is, if the font is not embedded, all bets are off: you cannot know what will happen. For example, the viewer might first see if the font is available (e.g. Helvetica is installed), then read a font-substitution list to see if it has instructions regarding Helvetica specifically, then try to figure out what kind of font might be a reasonable fall-back. Or it might ask the system's font configuration tools for Helvetica. Those tools might then see if Helvetica is covered by its substitution rules or otherwise try to find an alternative.

The font used might or might not be Helvetica. If not, it might, if you are lucky, at least be a sans somewhat like Helvetica (hopefully, but not necessarily, with the same metrics). It might or might not recognise, for example, ligatures correctly. If it doesn't, it might just leave gaps or it might use empty boxes. (It probably won't use e.g. 2 'f's - at least, I've never seen this relatively happy substitution for 'ff'.)

It is therefore a much better idea to:

1. get `uarial` working, if you can, if that's what you want to use;
2. embed another font, if you can't, even if it is not your first choice.

## `uarial`

The `uarial` package should work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Uncomment the map line if you are in either of the following 2 situations:
% uarial is installed, but the font map files for the system have not been correctly updated
% uarial is not installed at all, but you have put all the files from the package in your working directory (*.sty, *.fd, *.map, *.pfb, *.tfm, *.vf)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\pdfmapfile{+ua1.map}
\usepackage{uarial,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>uarial</code>]

The above is the font A030, installed with the get-non-free-fonts script (`getnonfreefonts-sys` variety).

To actually get a font called Arial, I can compile the following with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, provided a font with this name is installed for my system (e.g. in `/usr/share/fonts`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial]

I am guessing that when you say that you are using Helvetica, you are actually using NimbusSanL. This is what you would get using the above code with `helvet` in place of `uarial`.

[image: NimbusSansL]

Another option would be TeX Gyre Heros, which is supported by the `tgheros` package:

[image: TeX Gyre Heros]

Here, for the record, is a font which is actually called HelveticaNeue:

[image: HelveticaNeue]

## Embedding

Whether fonts are embedded or not depends on a range of factors:

1. TeX distribution and version;
2. kind of font;
3. compilation engine;
4. system-wide and, possibly, user-specific configuration;
5. more....

For a current (2015) installation of TeX Live from upstream, embedding is configured in `updmap.cfg`. System-wide defaults are in `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/web2c/updmap.cfg`. Instructions at the top of the file explain how to override settings system-wide and/or (in some cases) on a user-by-user basis.

For example, the line

```
LW35 URWkb
```

determines which fonts TeX Live uses when I load `helvet`. In this case (as I've not overridden this anywhere), it is using URW versions named according to the Karl Berry font-name scheme.

```
dvipsDownloadBase35 true
```

tells `dvips` to embed the 35 standard PS fonts.

```
pdftexDownloadBase14 true
```

tells `pdftex` to embed the 14 base PDF fonts while

```
dvipdfmDownloadBase14 true
```

tells `dvipdfm(x)` to do the same. Finally

```
kanjiEmbed noEmbed
```

tells `dvipdfmx` not to embed the Kanji fonts.

Beyond this, lines in individual `.map` files determine the lines which end up in the system-wide `.map` files, and these, too, can affect embedding e.g. by embedding subsets rather than entire fonts in certain cases.

On my system, I can override the settings from `updmap.cfg` above in a corresponding file in `TEXMFLOCAL`. I can also override them, I think, using a similar file in `TEXMFHOME`. However, the way in which `updmap` and `updmap-sys` work has changed more than once in recent editions of TeX Live. What is true for TL 2015, therefore, may or may not be true for TL 2013 or TL 2011 etc.

This all also depends, ultimately, on settings in `texmf.cnf` which determine which `TEXMF` trees are recognised, in which order they are searched and how they are to be searched. Again, this depends on TeX distribution, version and packaging, and on whether the default configuration has been altered by the system administrator.

If you are using Red Hat's packages, for example, the default configuration will be different, and, obviously, your system administrator may have made further changes.

## EDIT

Here's a comparison of 4 fonts on my machine (font names on the right).

[image: comparison]

Comment: Please could you explain how this is supposed to answer the question? I've already said that the package doesn't work in my case. Saying that it should doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @JessicaB You haven't said (1) what you've done i.e. the code you are using, or (2) what 'doesn't work' means. We're not mind readers ;). For all you've said, this might well help because you might be attempting to use the font using different code. It isn't possible to diagnose any problem without information about that problem. So *any* attempt to help is *inevitably* a shot in the dark. Of course, that makes it *unlikely* it will help: such is the intrinsic nature of such shots. I wrote this to check the package worked and posted it in case it helped. I'm sorry, but unsurprised, it doesn't.

Comment: @JessicaB Also, you only need to add the `.map`, as Ulrike Fischer explained. I've added some comments to the code about this.

Comment: I didn't tell you what code I am using because it is irrelevant to the question I asked. I did not ask why uarial is not working, I asked how to tell Latex not to embed Helvetica in the PDF output. So far all I've had is things telling me why I shouldn't want to do what I decided I do want to do, which I find rather impolite. Thank you for the additional comments though.

Comment: @JessicaB Actually, it is very much relevant as it matters what you mean by 'Helvetica'. It also matters which TeX distro you are using. Certainly in the case of TeX Live, it may also matter which edition you are using. And, in fact, it matters how that distribution is configured system-wide e.g. if steps have been taken to prevent users from overriding system-wide configuration. (The latter is unlikely, I think.) And, as Ulrike Fischer says, you could not embed Helvetica and get Helvetica. You could also not embed Helvetica and get neither Arial nor Helvetica e.g. Adobe's fallback sans.

Comment: @JessicaB I'm sorry, by the way, that you felt this was impolite. It is not. It is just that you have essentially asked what is known as an 'XY problem'. Typically XY problems do not reveal Y: they just ask how to X, where X is something of an odd thing to want to do. In this case, the reason for asking X is clear: you think X will achieve Y. But, in fact, X is not a good way to achieve Y at all. Moreover, there are better ways to achieve Y and achieving X would neither achieve Y nor be itself an easy thing to achieve. Hence, my initial answer. But my edits should help clarify the problem.

Comment: No, I haven't. I asked question X because I wanted an answer to X, and the reason I was thinking about X was Y. I did not say I believed X would achieve Y by itself. I did not say what I wanted was an answer to Y. You have assumed that you know what I want better than I do, and that is what I find impolite.

Comment: @JessicaB OK. That is not how I understood the question and I think it is not how Ulrike Fischer understood it given her comments. But if that's what you meant, that's what you meant even if it is not clear from what you said. In that case, you have to figure out a lot more about your system, as I say.

Comment: The uploaded PNGs are a little blurry, but it appears that first font (uarial/A030) is more like Helvetica than it is like Arial. Unfortunately, there are no "G" or "R" characters in the example text, but the "a", "r", and "t" all look more like the Helvetica characters.

Comment: @DanielWeissman Run the code on your machine and inspect the PDF. You can add whatever text you like. I'm not sure what your point is, quite.

Comment: @cfr I did that first, and got what appeared to be Helvetica rather than Arial. That's why I started squinting at the PNGs, to see if I had done something wrong or if you had the same issue. If uarial really does produce more Helvetica-like characters, I would suggest that people who specifically want Arial should maybe avoid it in favor of your solution producing actual Arial using LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX.

Comment: @DanielWeissman Arial is proprietary, so that's not a good solution in general but if it must be that specific font, you have to get that specific font and that means you need a proprietary font and there's no option.

Comment: @cfr In the spirit of your "XY" comments above, if in the future someone asks me "Help! I've got something in Helvetica that needs to be in Arial, and I can't get uarial to work!", rather than helping them get uarial working, I think I will suggest that if the difference between Helvetica and Arial matters for their purposes, then uarial won't be able to solve their problem. Either they should be satisfied with Helvetica, or they need the true proprietary Arial. But can you confirm that uarial is producing more Helvetica-like characters for you too?

Comment: @DanielWeissman See additional image above. On my machine, `ua1` is more like ArialMT and `uhv` is more like HelveticaNeue. Note that there is generally, by now, no saying what Arial or Helvetica will actually be on any system - unless, maybe, you get commercial fonts and you can at least say that this is *Adobe's Helvetica* or whatever. But somebody else may say Adobe have it wrong. So anybody told they must use one *as opposed to the other* needs to know what the Powers that Be think each font should look like. But `ua1` 'G', 'R' and 'Q' are more ArialMT-like than HelveticaNeue-like *here*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary of the key points that directly address the question:

Changing the font of Latex-generated text is generally unsuccessful because of the ligatures.

It is difficult to deliberately avoid embedding a font in the PDF because this is not controlled directly from Latex.