# Latex font not showing in pdf viewer plugin

Tags: fonts, viewers

I produced a pdf with LaTeX and uploaded it on a website.
The website uses a pdf viewer plugin to show it and

- all fonts that are not standard latex, are shown
- all fonts that are standard latex, are messed up

to be fair, i have set the default font to be sans serif, but that does not seem right to be a problem.

What should i do?

- someone told me to use google font, is there an equivalent google font that is exactly the standard LaTeX font?
- would including the fonts in the pdf itself address this?
- other?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use a fast solution. Print to PDF (from the PDF) with settings for all fonts embedded option. It is good specially when you have some figures imported from other PDFs as well.
If you want to solve the issue in its right way, check the answer here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10392/99176